# How to Resolve Encountered two children with the same key React.js

Tags: reactjs, key

Been having trouble getting this 'Encountered two children with the same key' error sorted. I've gone through a few threads regarding this issue and none of the answers seem to work in my situation. I want to avoid using index as well as its discouraged.

```
useEffect(() => {
const Items = locations.map((location) => {
  return {
    header: location.description,
    key: location.code,
    content: location.phoneNumber,
    image: {
      as: Avatar,
    },
    code: location.code,
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
const Items = locations.map((location) => {
  return {
    header: location.description,
    key: location.code,
    content: location.phoneNumber,
    image: {
      as: Avatar,
    },
    code: location.code,
  };
});
```

The key location.code is not unique and is used multiple times, you need unique keys. A fix could be this :

```
useEffect(() => {
const Items = locations.map((location,index) => {
  return {
    header: location.description,
    key: index,
    content: location.phoneNumber,
    image: {
      as: Avatar,
    },
    code: location.code,
  };
});
```

But the best would be something like a unique id. Maybe location.id if thats available..

Answer (score 0):

Is there a unique id in the location object? in which case, that is the perfect solution. Using the index is discouraged, but could potentially be combined with your location.code and concatenated.

```
useEffect(() => {
const Items = locations.map((location,index) => {
  return {
    header: location.description,
    key: index + location.code,
    content: location.phoneNumber,
    image: {
      as: Avatar,
    },
    code: location.code,
  };
});
```